# Symbols instead of characters on my Windows XP computer

Tags: windows-xp

For some reason, my computer started using symbols instead of characters in some places, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it?

Look at the tabs and toolbar in this screenshot for an example of the issue:

[image: symbols in Chrome toolbar and tabs]

Comment: Please refer error image to understand more about the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help:
Start -> Control panel -> Regional and Language options -> Languages -> Details -> **SELECT EN ENGLISH** and remove that other language

Answer (score 0):

Some system fonts may have been deleted by mistake.

1. Try running `sfc /scannow` from the Command Prompt.
2. The complete list of fonts installed by default in XP can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/winxp.htm). You can open a Command Prompt window and navigate to the **i386 folder** of your Windows XP disc, then use `expand` to expand and copy any missing fonts to the Fonts folder. For example:

   `expand E:\i386\Sserife.fo_ %windir%\fonts\Sserife.fon`

   `expand E:\i386\Arial.tt_ %windir%\fonts\Arial.ttf`
3. Make sure the `Advanced Appearance` dialog (`right-click Desktop / Properties / Appearance tab / Advanced button`) does not have any missing fonts selected:

   [image]
4. If none of the above helps, try a repair install of the OS.